# Make hyperlink in MS Word Add-in

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, add-in

is there any way to programmaticaly add an hyperlink to the selected text in a MS Word Add-In?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below converts selected text into a hyperlink which points to the Microsoft site:

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range currentRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;

        if (currentRange != null)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink hp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink)
                currentRange.Hyperlinks.Add(currentRange, "http://www.microsoft.com");

        }
```

The actual text of the hyperlink,by default, will be your selected text. If you need this text to be of different value, for instance - the actual url address, you can simply change the TextToDisplay property:

```
hp.TextToDisplay = "http://www.microsoft.com";
```

I'm not sure exactly how dynamic your logic needs to be but I believe the above example will give you a push in the right direction.

Comment: Hello, in your code above, it seems like you arent using hp after setting it. May I know what is the purpose of setting up variable hp?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to do this in VBA, it's

```
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, ...
```

Sytnax:

```
expression.Add(Anchor, Address, SubAddress, ScreenTip, TextToDisplay, Target)
```