# C# interop word: insert hyperlink in a paragraph (with a loop)

Tags: c#, hyperlink, ms-word, office-interop

So I trying to generate a word document by using the data in Access DB. with that, I would like to insert some hyperlinks of files in somewhere in the shared drive. basically I would like something similar to this:
[image]

So far, I think to gather all my URL path into a List and loop it. But I am not sure how to display those hyperlink in the doc.

```
              //Add the documents
            //the title 
            Paragraph para12 = wordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
            para12.Range.Font.Size = 12;
            para12.Range.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
            para12.Range.Text = "Related Documents : " + Convert.ToChar(11);
            para12.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

            //add the hyperlink
            Hyperlinks theLinks = wordDoc.Hyperlinks;
            foreach (STRD_Stakeholder_Related_Document item in STRD)
            {
                string[] split = item.STRD_FilePath.Split('\\');

                para12.Range.Text = split.Last() + Convert.ToChar(11);
                //do something
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make hyperlink in MS Word Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534231/make-hyperlink-in-ms-word-add-in)

Comment: In C#, is there a similar thing: [Hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534231/make-hyperlink-in-ms-word-add-in)

Comment: Yes, the object model is identical